# Setting up IPv6 on XP

Tags: windows-xp, ipv6, teredo

I'm trying to work out a nice user friendly way of accessing IPv6 on windows XP. While on linux, miredo does a good job, without needing a tunnel broker, i can't seem to get teredo, its windows equivilent working. I have IPv6 enabled in network settings for my primary system and teredo started with netsh- and i can't ping a ip address that works with a system that i know works, or access an ipv6 website on firefox

So the question is, how do i get teredo working so that i can access ipv6 sites on firefox, and ping a server, and generally be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually it turned out that UPNP wasn't working, and the box was DMZed. Turning off DMZ fixed it.