# issues switching to IPv6

Tags: windows, ipv6

Currently have a local LAN with one WindowsServer2003 machine and several XP machines.  Everything works normal, users can share folders, etc.

Decided to install the IPv6 protocol on all machines, and unchecked `Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)`

Now, the machines can't connect to each other.  What am I missing to enable IPv6 on my LAN?

Comment: Does [this](http://superuser.com/questions/102134/setting-up-ipv6-on-xp) help ?

Comment: Are you sure your router/switch support IPv6?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps looking through [this](http://www.telekom.hu/static/sw/download/IPv6_user_guide5_eng.pdf) article will help. It's for a home LAN but most of the stuff is relevant to a Server based LAN too.
[This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775579(WS.10).aspx) is the oficial Microsoft document on setting up an IPv6 LAN

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer is the only IPv6 capable application in those operating systems, however the DNS client cannot do lookups over IPv6, but can lookup IPv6 addresses.

Either upgrade or run a dual stack network. You can workaround the lack of DNS support by using a third party DNS proxy.